# How to execute operation on a dataframe according to another dataframe?

Tags: r, dataframe

I've got a dataframe named `df` on which I want to convert amounts in certain columns in euros (given by the variable $currency.Code). For this, I've got another dataframe named `taux_change_vers_EUR` with two variables: (1) the name of the currency, (2) the exchange rate to convert in euros.

I would like to apply the coefficients of the second column of my dataframe `taux_change_vers_EUR` to several columns of my dataframe `df`. The problem is that my df is quite large and so the operation has to be optimized (nor for loop). Do you have an idea?

Here is a part of code. This code does not work but does show you what I'm expecting:

```
for (devise in unique(df$currency.Code)){
    df[df$currency.Code==devise,c(4:37,44:48)] <- df[df$currency.Code==devise,c(4:37,44:48)]*rep(as.numeric(taux_change_vers_EU    R[taux_change_vers_EUR[,1]==devise,2]),39)
}
```

Here is how my second dataframe looks like:

```
taux_change_vers_EUR
     V1        V2
1   USD   1.14720
2   CAD   1.48836
3   GBP   0.87869
4   EUR   1.00000
5  <NA>   1.00000
6   DKK   6.50221
7   SEK   9.10235
8   PLN   3.76455
9   CZK  22.49280
10  NOK   8.28273
11  TRY   6.12973
12  TWD  30.98320
13  CNY   6.92256
14  HKD   7.83296
15  JPY 113.16000
```

Comment: Provide example input dataframes, and expected output. I am guessing `merge` should be a solution. Merge 2 dataframes on `V1`(Currency), then multiply `valueCol` with `V2`.

Comment: Hey there, could you please post a code example that properly illustrates your situation and that we can run? I recommend reading [this excellent guide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) and then editing your question!

Comment: Thx @zx8754 it worked perfectly!. Sorry Oliver Baumann I'll read it!

Comment: @T.Ciffréo, if you found an answer to be useful and solve your problem, please consider marking it as accepted! This will award both you and the person who wrote the answer [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use *match*:

```
# example data borrowed from @JohnCoene
df1 <- data.frame(
  currency = c("USD", "GBP", "JPY", "CAD"),
  rate = c(1.2, 0.9, 0.8, 1.5))

set.seed(1); df2 <- data.frame(
  value = 1,
  currency = sample(df1$currency, 5, replace = TRUE))

df2$velueNew <- df2$value * df1$rate[ match(df2$currency, df1$currency) ]
df2
#   value currency velueNew
# 1     1      GBP      0.9
# 2     1      GBP      0.9
# 3     1      JPY      0.8
# 4     1      CAD      1.5
# 5     1      USD      1.2
```

Comment: well done, didnt know that -- how fast is it compared to merge?

Comment: @gpier depends on input datasets, but I would guess about 10 times faster than merge.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to merge the two `data.frame`s by the actual currency then convert. Below is a reproducible examples using `dplyr`.

```
library(dplyr)

# create dummy data
currencies <- data.frame(
    currency = c("USD", "GBP", "JPY", "CAD"),
    rate = c(1.2, .9, .8, 1.5)
)

moneyz <- data.frame(
    value = runif(100, 5, 100),
    currency = sample(currencies$currency, 100, replace = TRUE)
)

# merge and convert
moneyz %>% 
    left_join(currencies, by = "currency") %>% # merge
    mutate(
        converted = value * rate # convert
    )
```

We simply merge the two tables together to obtain one table with the value, the currency it is in and the appropriate rate to convert to EUR.

Answer (score 0):

I created an example which you can reuse by running this:

```
df <- structure(list(c("EUR", "EUR", "USD", "CAD"), c(1654, 68797, 
                                                6546, 736), c("CNY", "HKD", "HKD", "HKD"), c(6876, 63, 687, 354
                                                )), .Names = c("currency1", "amount1", "currency2", "amount2"
                                                ), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```

So a fast way to do this, *provided you have unique currencies in `taux_change_vers_EUR`* is using a `merge` for each one of your columns of interest in `df`, which you can even loop through.

```
cur1.rate  <- merge(df, taux_change_vers_EUR, by.x="currency1", by.y="V1", all.y=FALSE)
cur2.rate  <- merge(cur1.rate, taux_change_vers_EUR, by.x="currency2", by.y="V1", all.y=FALSE)
result <- cur2.rate
result$amount1.eur <- result$amount1*result$V2.x
result$amount2.eur <- result$amount2*result$V2.y
result
  currency2 currency1 amount1 amount2    V2.x    V2.y amount1.eur amount2.eur
1       CNY       EUR    1654    6876 1.00000 6.92256    1654.000  47599.5226
2       HKD       CAD     736     354 1.48836 7.83296    1095.433   2772.8678
3       HKD       EUR   68797      63 1.00000 7.83296   68797.000    493.4765
4       HKD       USD    6546     687 1.14720 7.83296    7509.571   5381.2435
```